# len(alg.feature_importances_) does not coincide with len(input variables)

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

If I ask for the feature importance score of my LightGBM model, I end up with a longer string than the number of input variables (predictors):

```
 len(alg.feature_importances_) = 50
 len(predictors) = 46
```

The prediction setup I use is the following:

```
    alg = lgb.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type = 'gbdt', colsample_bytree = 0.75,
                             importance_type = 'split',
                             learning_rate = 0.1, max_depth = 7,
                             n_estimators = 500,  num_leaves = 10, reg_lambda= 0.01, min_child_samples=25) 

alg.fit(train[predictors], train[target])
alg.predict(test[predictors])
alg.proba(test[predictors])
```

Then the  feature importance's obtained are the following: `alg.feature_importances_`

```
array([83, 88, 14, 10, 17, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

The input variables (predictors) are the following: `print(predictors)`

```
['Prob1',
 'Prob2',
 'Comeback1',
 'Comeback2',
 'compare srp_1',
 'compare srp_2',
 'meang-W5_1',
 'meang-W5_2',
 'ratings-W100_1',
 'ratings-W100_2',
 'meang-W100_1',
 'meang-W100_2',
 'meangr-W5_1',
 'meangr-W5_2',
 'meangr-W100_1',
 'meangr-W100_2',
 'meangs-W5_1',
 'meangs-W5_2',
 'meangs-W100_1',
 'meangs-W100_2',
 'meanp-W20_1',
 'meanp-W20_2',
 'meanp-W1000_1',
 'meanp-W1000_2',
 'meanrp-W20_1',
 'meanrp-W20_2',
 'meanrp-W1000_1',
 'meanrp-W1000_2',
 'meansp-W20_1',
 'meansp-W20_2',
 'meansp-W1000_1',
 'meansp-W1000_2',
 'meanrp + meansp-W20_1',
 'meanrp + meansp-W20_2',
 'meanrp + meansp-W100_1',
 'meanrp + meansp-W100_2',
 'scoregames_1',
 'scoregames_2',
 'setsscore_1',
 'setsscore_2',    
 'ratings_1',
 'ratings_2',
 'ratings-W100_1',
 'ratings-W100_2',
 'momentum_1',
 'momentum_2']
```

For me this is a problem since I don't know which feature score belongs to which variable. Looks like some features/variables produce multiple feature scores.

Answer (score 1):

`feature_importance` only returns a numpy array, so the missing labels are not a sign that the model does not have the feature names, but is the regular behavior.

I usually plot the feature importance, where the labels are displayed. From the code, that plots I got, what actually needs to be done. It is:

```
importance = booster.feature_importance(importance_type='gain') # or 'split'
feature_name = booster.feature_name()
list(zip(feature_name, importance))
```

If you work with the sklearn api and don't have the handle of the booster, you get it like this (if alg is your sklearn wrapper object, that you trained):

```
booster= alg.booster_
```

If you want to plot the importance directly, you can do this as follows:

```
lightgbm.plot_importance(booster, importance_type='gain')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes alg is my booster. I don't use the dataset api but the fit method(think those are similar?). So the above code does not work. If I were to use the dataset api, how would I proceed with the predictions? I do however prefer the method I have now.

Comment: I just recognized, that the method always returns the value withot labels. If you want to try the native api, you can check this example: kaggle.com/ezietsman/simple-python-lightgbm-example.

Comment: Okay will do. Do you know how I can return the belonging probabilities with this native api. 'model.predict(x)' returns a binary number in case of a classification problem. I need the probabilities that come with it, do you know how to obtain those?

Comment: Are you sure, `predict` returns integers in your case? in my case it returns the probabilites, then I have to apply a threshold (usually 0.5 to decide between 0 and 1). In case of multiclass classification you get a twodimensional matrix with a probability for each class.